# Copying files from Bootable USB to local Drive in %post script of kickstart

Tags: linux, centos, kickstart

I have created bootable USB with custom folder in it, After installation i want to copy files from USB to local directory, Following is kickstart file %post section

```
%post --nochroot --erroronfail --log=/mnt/sysimage/root/ks-post.log
cp -af /run/install/repo/custom/Router_CFG.ini /var/lib/tftpboot
%end
```

Above code throws error that /var/lib/tftpboot directory doesnt exist, i removed --nochroot

```
%post --erroronfail --log=/mnt/sysimage/root/ks-post.log
cp -af /run/install/repo/custom/Router_CFG.ini /var/lib/tftpboot
%end
```

and now it complain that USB mount point (**/run/install/repo**) is not available.

Then i tried to mount USB drive

```
%post --erroronfail --log=/mnt/sysimage/root/ks-post.log
mkdir /mnt/myusb
usbblkid=$(blkid -L "CentOS 7 x86_64")
mount $usbblkid /mnt/myusb
cp -af /mnt/myusb/custom/Router_CFG.ini /var/lib/tftpboot
%end
```

Now its throwing error

```
mount: Special device /dev/sdc1 doese not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first attempt was *almost* correct. Try it this way:

```
%post --nochroot --erroronfail --log=/mnt/sysimage/root/ks-post.log
cp -af /run/install/repo/custom/Router_CFG.ini /mnt/sysimage/var/lib/tftpboot
%end
```

When using `%post --nochroot`, the root of the new system will be at `/mnt/sysimage` so you'll need to prefix it to all the paths referring to the new system you're installing. The installation media will be at `/run/install/repo`.

If you remove the `--nochroot`, then the root of the new system will be at `/`, but the installation media will be inaccessible without extra steps.
Your second attempt might have worked if done like this (adapted from a working RHEL7.2 postinstall configuration I made and tested earlier):

```
%post --erroronfail --log=/root/ks-post.log
mkdir /mnt/myusb
mount /dev/disk/by-label/CentOS*7*x86_64 /mnt/myusb
cp -af /mnt/myusb/custom/Router_CFG.ini /var/lib/tftpboot
umount /mnt/myusb
rmdir /mnt/myusb
%end
```

Comment: I've tried to use that approach but the mount throws a 

`"mount: /dev/<path>.... is already mounted or /mnt/usb busy"`

error

Comment: @GillesPion I'm facing the same issue. Did you ever work your way around it?

Comment: @BlackSpy Apparently you're using a version that does not allow multiple mounts of the same filesystem, or your pick for the mountpoint (`/mnt/usb`) is what the installer is already using (great minds think alike :-) so add something like `lsblk` or `df` into your `%post` script, and make one test run to see what your installation environment actually looks like, then either use an existing mount if one exists, or pick another name for your custom mountpoint.

Comment: @telcoM thanks for the response. I did try those but couldn't get it to mount. Eventually decided to move the content to another partition (3rd one now) that I know won't be used by the OS installer and mount that. This seems to work well.

Comment: @BlackSpy I know it is late, but if some one else come here for the mounting issue, I was able to mount the USB inside the chroot using the read only option, as I only need to to copy files from the usb to the disk. `mount -o ro /dev/disk/by-label/MYLABEL /mnt/myusb`